# Saving file with month name not number in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to save file with month name not number. At the moment my output for the below code is SD recon 09.2020 but I would like XX recon August 2020.

```
'''Saving the sheet with correct naming convention
Sub newfilesave()
Dim Filename
Filename = "XX Recon "
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs ("\\xxx\xxx\xxx " & Filename & Format(Now(), "MM.YYYY") & ".xlsm")
MsgBox "File Saved in folder with latest date"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to read the `Format` [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications):

> **Date symbols**
>
> *mmmm*: Displays full month names
>
> *yyyy*: 100-9999 (Three- or Four-digit year)

So all you need is

`Format(Date, "mmmm yyyy")` instead of `Format(Now(), "MM.YYYY")`.

<sup>1. The use of `Date` as opposed to `Now()` is personal preference, either will work.</sup>